# how can I get a log file in angular using ngx-logger?

Tags: angular, logging

How to set logs to file in angular rather that printing logs in console. I’m using ngx-logger. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: wheere are you deploying the application

Comment: I'm just running the application using ng serve commad on Visual studio Code.I'm new to angular.Log is printing on web console.I need to get that log to file.

Comment: if you are using azure or aws you can directly log the errors to app insights / cloudwatch

Comment: Without connecting to third party. is there a way to keep client side log using  angular?

Comment: its not a 3rd party, its a cloud provider.

Answer (score 3):

It's  not possible to write to a file from angular, since it is purely on client side.

The possible solution would be to send to the server and write to a file or use any of the cloud provider such as azure/aws existing feature appInsights/cloudwatch to log the errors.

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan for your quick reply.I'll try on this.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://github.com/A1rPun/ngx-logger there's a function to post the log to the server end. if there's no function, modify the library and add one.

```
//Post to an endpoint somewhere on the internets
logToEndpoint(logMessage: any): void {
  this.http.post(url, logMessage);
}
```

Example payload

```
{
  'level': 'info',
  'message': 'Hello log!',
  'app': 'MyApp',
  'timestamp': '1337133371337'
}
```

Comment: it looks like normal `http` post call then what is the use of `ngx-logger` here ?